# Method onchange couldn't be defined by OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I would charge an information automatically when I choose another,
when I add this function to my class I got that error
No handler found.

This is my code:

```
def onchange_medium(self, cr, uid, ids, division_id, context=None):
        if division_id:
            division = self.pool.get('standard.division').browse(cr, uid, division_id, context)
            return {'value':{'medium_id':division.medium_id.id,}}
        return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used openerp, but from the [docs](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/06_misc_on_change_tips.html), i think you need to register onchange_medium in your view.

```
<field name="name" on_change="onchange_medium(division_id)"/>
```

Here name is the name of the field that changed. Probably division_id. Hope that helps, if not have a look at the docs.

Comment: thanks HeinzKurt for ur answer,  I used bad espace in begining of method that's why, I use IDE eclipse and it shows me the error